# How to return file(s) with web service in PHP

Tags: php, xml, web-services

I'm developing a web service which returns a file for clients request. How can I attach the file in the returned XML file or any other ways? The client is not web based so I can't simply write any javascript to handle that. The web service was written in PHP. Any concepts or sample code would be great help!

Comment: Why use XML at all? Why don't you return just the file contents?